# Не работает функция JS в строке браузера

Tags: javascript

```
javascript:(document.getElementById('head').style['display'] = 'none';)
```

Не подскажите почему может не работать код, вставляю его в строку браузера и по сути должен убираться див с названием head, тестирую на странице:
http://m.auto.vesti.ru/doc.html?id=567453&cid=21

Comment: Должен прятаться div с атрибутом id равным 'head'. Но такого на странице нет.

Comment: на странице есть класс 'head', id нет.

Comment: Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос отметьте это, если ответ исчерпывающий то закройте вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByClassName('head')[0].style.display="none";})();
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, очень было нужно!)